# MySQL Add Month To Date While Less Than Some Other Date

Tags: mysql, date

I have a problem where I need to add, for example, 1 month to a date while the date is <= some other date.

For example:

```
set @startdt = '2018-01-15';
set @maxdt = '2018-05-31';

set @dt = @startdt;

while (@dt <= @maxdt) do
    select @dt;
    set @dt = date_add(@dt, interval 1 month);
end while
```

The output will be

```
2018-01-15
2018-02-15
2018-03-15
2018-04-15
2018-05-15
```

The above is correct but if @startdt='2018-01-31' the output will be

```
2018-01-31
2018-02-28
2018-03-28
2018-04-28
2018-05-28
```

What I need, ideally, would to return (when `@startdt='2018-01-31'` )

```
2018-01-31
2018-02-28
2018-03-31
2018-04-30   
2018-05-31
```

I tried the below

```
set @d = cast('2018-01-31' as datetime);
set @dy = day(@d);

set @d2 = date_add(@d, interval 1 month);
set @d2y = cast(year(@d2) as char(4));
set @d2m = cast(month(@d2) as char(2));
set @d2i = cast(STR_TO_DATE(concat(@d2y,',',@d2m,',',@dy), '%Y, %m, %d') as datetime);

set @d3 = date_add(@d2i, interval 2 month);
set @d3y = cast(year(@d3) as char(4));
set @d3m = cast(month(@d3) as char(2));
set @d32 = STR_TO_DATE(@d3y,@d3y, @dy, '%Y, %m, %d');

select @d,  @d2i, @d3, @d32, @d2y, @d2m, @dy;
```

and the output does not make sense as `@d2i` is coming out as `2018-02-31`. `@d3` and `@d32` come out as `NULL`.

I think I am missing the wood for the trees. Any help anyone provides will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the [`last_day()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) function can help? What if `@startdt = 2018-02-28` (i.e. last day of Feb), what should the day in March be in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is rather than adding 1 month at a time to the date, add an increasing number of months to the start date each time:

```
set @startdt = '2018-01-31';
set @maxdt = '2018-05-31';
set @m = 1;
set @dt = @startdt;

while (@dt <= @maxdt) do
    select @dt;
    set @dt = @startdt + interval m month;
    set @m = @m + 1;
end while
```

Output:

```
2018-01-31
2018-02-28
2018-03-31
2018-04-30   
2018-05-31
```

Comment: That is so simple! Thank you. it does what I want it to do.

I cannot upvote as I have less than 15 points. Come on StackOverflow!